# Semaphore Timeout Period

Tags: .net, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I've recently wiped and reinstalled/configured all the components of my web and DB servers. I'm running IIS 6, .NET 3.5, SQL Server 2005. The two servers are separate VM's in the same domain. My web app functions perfectly... 90% of the time. But every now and then I get this error or a generic runtime error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The semaphore timeout period has expired.)

Can you guys give me some leads on where to start troubleshooting? I really think I've missed something in IIS.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can't see why this question shouldn't be closed all of the answers on it are trash. including the chosen answer.

Comment: Off-topic on Stack Overflow. It's about server administration.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

After troubleshooting this for hours and sitting on the phone with my hosting group they discovered that there was a problem with their networking configuration. The solution was made clearer when during my testing one of the VM's suddenly couldn't find the domain, and a simple 'ping' to the IP of each box from the other would occasionally time out. This ruled out DNS entirely. After the hosting group applied the proper configuration on their end the app has been stable and FAST!

Thanks for everyone's help!

Comment: could you detail on what network configuration was updated? What was the correct full fix? Thanks!

Comment: No details but this answer got 7 votes... While some answers has full details but gets negative votes. Welcome to StackOverflow.

Comment: It's a surprisingly helpful answer despite the absolute lack of details. In my case it was a faulty network switch.

Answer (score 8):

A few pointers are [**here**](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqldataaccess/thread/d99b4d8e-feeb-43cb-80af-3d4826340a2c/) .Basically the error is being thrown by the network layer and SQL server is just reporting it.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

Well I would start by ensuring I'm running the latest version of my virtual machine's network drivers.

Sounds like comms is failing between your 2 VMS. Try opening a TCP socket between the two machines and see if it dies after a certain amount of time.

Answer (score 2):

Can you double check the load on the db server? We do get them once in a while in our dev env, but never in the prod env.

Comment: The load should be fine, this error was produced while only one person was testing it.

Comment: Load here doesn't necessarily mean the number of people using the application, but the number of processes running on the db server and the amount od cpu/network the db instance is being allocated.

Answer (score 1):

I will post my experience just in case it might help someday somebody ;)

At the end of the year, just trying to connect remotely to our servers from a place far, far away, using my phone. I noticed that I could not login to one windows server via remote desktop (black screen), nor I could connect from a Windows Application to the same server.

As soon as I changed from my phone to a different connection (via a NightHawk M1 mobile router), it was all good.

As I have read, is is about NETWORKING issues mainly, so DO NOT PANIC and try to find the guilty there.

Hope it helps,
R

Answer (score 0):

Late to the game, but I was getting this same error with a .NET web app/MS SQL. Site hosted in IIS on GoDaddy VPS, hosting has multiple IPs, DB hosted at Azure.

I believe my problem was (idiot!), I simply forgot to put the GD site's dedicated IP addresses from GD into the Azure firewall for the SQL server.  For some strange reason the traffic gets to/from GD/Azure outside of the actual IP address for the website (the IIS binding addresses) and works.

But more often than not the actual IIS binding addresses are the ones calling out to Azure to interact with the SQL services.  I corrected the firewall settings on Azure to include the correct IPs from GoDaddy and (knock on wood) the semaphore error seems gone now.

In other words, before you start looking for big problems, start simple and be sure to check easy things like network/firewall settings.

Answer (score -1):

check whether the stored procedure has any line 
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED

For me this was the issue