# SqlException - A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, sqlexception, hangfire

I am coding a MVC 5 internet application and I have a recurring task that executes every hour. This task updates some model objects using a DbContext class. The application is deployed as an Azure website.

I am getting the following error every few hours:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A transport-level
>   error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider:
>   TCP Provider, error: 0 - The semaphore timeout period has expired.)
>   ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The semaphore timeout period has expired

Why is this? Also, how can I prevent this from happening?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try the kb http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/325487

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/551282/semaphore-timeout-period

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Semaphore Timeout Period](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/551282/semaphore-timeout-period)

Comment: This can be useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/551282/semaphore-timeout-period

Comment: Off-topic on Stack Overflow. It's about server administration.

Answer (score -1):

Got this error when I was trying to connect to a database using SQL Server Management Studio. When I tried using a different internet connection, was able to connect successfully. Once successful earlier internet connection which failed also worked well in the next login.